# http://localhost/myapp/assets/i18n/en.json not found when angular 6 code deployed on windows 7 IIS server

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying deploying my application to IIS server on windows 7 PC. The web address is

http://localhost/myapp

1. I installed URL rewrite.
2. Here is my web.config content

```html
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
       <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My application runs very good using "ng serve" on my computer. When I deployed on IIS on windows 7 PC, the application cannot access resources like images, json files. I got 404 error. I think there is something wrong in my web.config file. The file, en.json, is located c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\assets\i18n folder after it is deployed.
Please help.

Comment: In IIS do you have default website mapped to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp` directory? Please share the details of how you have setup the Angular6 app in IIS

Comment: Sounds like you need to set your `base` href tag to `/myapp` https://angular.io/guide/deployment#base-tag

Comment: The application is mapped to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp. The base_href is "/myapp/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that IIS 7 doesn't have ".json" as default file extension. Here is web.config to add the ".json".

```html
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".json" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The ".json" file extension is a default one in ISS 8. I have to remove it before adding it.

Comment: I searched on all other related articles and had no issues with code. I was just missing above mime type configuration in web.config and it saved me from 404 error on hosting environment (Azure). I had no issues when I ran this on my local/debug env.

Answer (score 0):

altere o Web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

 

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
   <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".json" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
</system.webServer>

 

</configuration>
```